React native is not running on Mac
Showing error after running "npm start" command
I created a bare reactive native project and tried to run it without any changes done in the project. After running the project it showed me this error what should I do to make it working? Should I uninstall node and reinstall again or any path need to be changed? please help me

package.json is placed inside demo folder that's why you are getting error.

As I can see you are not in your Project directory. I mean your project name is 'demo' and you are running command 'npm start' and 'npm run ios' outside of your 'demo' project which name is React Native.
You have to go to your current working project name 'demo' by typing this command ... cd demo then you have to run this command npm start or npm run ios.
